# Parsing multiple lines of text into separate strings

Tags: c, parsing

I am trying to parse multiple lines of text from a .txt file, in c. The way i have it right now only parses a single line. I was wondering how to scan through multiple lines and save them in different strings

My code:

```
void parser();
#define ROOM_STRING_LENGTH 10000
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  parser();

  return 0;
}


void parser()
{
  FILE * rooms;
  int i;
  char c;
  char roomStrings[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];

  rooms = fopen("assets/rooms.txt", "r");

  if(rooms == NULL)
  {
    printf("error opening file\n");
  }

  fscanf(rooms, "%s", roomStrings);
  while((c=fgetc(rooms))!='\n')
  {

    roomStrings[i] = c;
    i++;
  }
  printf("%s\n", roomStrings);
  fclose(rooms);
}
```

Comment: A short example input file and an indication of the biggest file that you expect to be able to handle would make answering this a little easier (it informs the solution strategy quite a bit). Also, if this is a homework problem, that'd be nice to know too.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely want to use fgets() instead of fgetc().  That reads an entire line at a time.  [Here is an explanation of fgets().](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

If you know how many lines you're reading, you can just make roomStrings to be an array of strings, like this: `char roomStrings[NUM_LINES][ROOM_STRING_LENGTH]`.  Otherwise, there are several ways to have it be dynamically sized.